# GDC equivalent to dmd's -main option

Tags: d, gdc

Does the GNU D Compiler provide a flag similar to the `-main` flag of dmd? I've checked the options list for both GCC itself and `gdmd` (designed to take similar arguments to dmd, but use gdc instead), and couldn't find anything like it.

If such a flag exists, what can I do to get similar behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a module that contains a main function guarded by a version block.

```
version(emitMain) void main() {}
```

If you would normally use '-main', now use '-version=emitMain'. This way your build system does not have to take care of not including this module for your normal builds that already have a main function.

Answer (score 0):

GDMD *does* contain a `-main` argument. What version are you using?
From `GDMD D Compiler 2.068 using gdc (Gentoo 8.1.0 p1.2) 8.1.0`:

```
Usage:
  ...
  -main        add default main() (e.g for unittesting)
```

It works on my machine, and it should too on yours. Please use an updated GDMD.